# Check whether website is using sitemap and robots files

Tags: php

How do I know whether the website is using robot.txt and sitemap.txt? I have done extracting keyword, description, title; however I am unable to find the way to code to check whther the website is using robot.txt and sitemap.txt.

I am doing something like this http://www.seoptimer.com/report/loadster.in/5553240531d12

Answer (score 2):

Use file_get_contents:

```
$robotsContents = file_get_contents("http://targetdomain.com/robots.txt");
$sitemapContents = file_get_contents("http://targetdomain.com/sitemap.xml");
```

Check if contents are false, false will mean 404 Not Found, then check if it's not HTML contents (because some sites redirect every URL) with `strpos($robotsContents, '<html') === false`, if there is no  tag, that mean it can be txt ou xml file.

So:

```
function pathExistsAndIsNotHtml($path) {
    $contents = @file_get_contents($path);
    return ! empty($contents) && strpos($contents, '<html') === false;
}
if(pathExistsAndIsNotHtml("http://targetdomain.com/robots.txt")) {
    echo '<a href="http://targetdomain.com/robots.txt">http://targetdomain.com/robots.txt</a>';
} else {
    echo 'There is no robots.txt';
}
if(pathExistsAndIsNotHtml("http://targetdomain.com/sitemap.xml")) {
    echo '<a href="http://targetdomain.com/sitemap.xml">http://targetdomain.com/sitemap.xml</a>';
} else {
    echo 'There is no sitemap.xml';
}
```

Comment: thank you, its working and here i don't want to show the contents I just wanted to read the contents and display the http://targetdomain.com/robots.txt link. how to do it?

Comment: thank you .. now i want to download it in pdf format

Comment: This is not the purpose of Stackoverflow, you will not get your complete code here. We answear one trageted question on a post. If the answear is correct, please validate it, and in a other post, give your code and what is blocking you.